# How can I make custom UI controls for the QuickTime Player?

Tags: javascript, html, quicktime

How can I make custom UI controls for the QuickTime Player in HTML pages? (like Apple does on its site)

Comment: That is a reason why i am starting to hate Apple. You should not follow them. They don't support web at all. Why not use mp4, it works on every browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [QuickTime JavaScript API](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html).

Make sure to check the section "Controlling QuickTime Using JavaScript", for some code examples.

You would be able to do the following:

```
<div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       QT_WriteOBJECT('MyMovie.mov', '180','160', '',
       'obj#id', 'movie1', 'emb#name', 'movie1', 'enablejavascript', 'true');
    </script>
</div>

<p>Play and Stop Movie: <br>
    <a href="javascript:document.movie1.Play();">Play Movie</a><br>
    <a href="javascript:document.movie1.Stop();">Stop Movie</a><br>
</p>
```